# Getting the time in 24 hour format

Tags: java, datetime

I have to print the date in 24 hour format rite now as shown 
below the date is printed in 12 hr format i want it to be get printed in 24 hour format as the file will be containg UK timestamp

```
String currDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm").format(new Date());
System.out.println("ABC_0101-"+currDate);
ABC_0101-07-09-2013-11-16
```

Please advise as shown above the file name is ABC_0101 followd by a seprator "-" and then
the time stamp 07-09-2013-11-16 , please advise how the time particulary will be printed in 24 hour format

Answer (score 8):

you could use `HH` or `KK` to format hour in 24.

> H Hour in day (0-23) 
>   k Hour in day (1-24)

format you can use `MM-dd-yyyy-kk-mm`  or `MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm`.

Comment: so simple date format should be like what could you please post the updated example

Comment: Thanks seen the updated code what K represent as you have advise please a=explain in detail

Comment: its actually small `k` and it represent hour of a day in `1-24` format.

Answer (score 2):

Currently what have you done is working. and that will give you time in 24 hour format. change your system time to some where in afternoon and check it.

```
    String currDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm").format(new Date());
    System.out.println(currDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused. It looks like your code will print in 24 hour format to me? It says here that HH represents the 24 hour format

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

HH is exactly what you need. It's 24 hour format. See SimpleDateFormat API. Change your computer time to 16:00 and try your code again to test.

Comment: Thanks a lot could you please also advise now what wil be updated format if possible please paste the updted code as I have shown